# Render arbitrary jade in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

We've got a "catch-all" in `app.js` that renders a `.jade` file if it exists:

```
app.get('*', routes.render);
```

> index.js

```
render: function(req, res) {
  fs.exists('views' + req.url + '.jade', function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
      //substring: "/admin" -> "admin"
      res.render(req.url.substring(1));
    } else {
      res.status(404);
      res.render('404', {url: req.url});
    }
  });
}
```

Problem is, we've either got to move everything we don't want rendered this way into another folder, which is a hassle, or create a manual blacklist.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I guess this is only for static pages?

Comment: Only for pages that don't require additional parameters (for example "About Us")

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples of how most apps do:

- Apache renders everything in the folder. If you want to hide access to a subfolder, you do that with an htaccess in this subfolder.
- Define each route yourself. This'd mean having a whitelist in your case. (In some array or something.)
- Keep the routes in the database. This allows you to handle permissions easily.

I haven't often seen the blacklist way. Why? Because of a simple security principle: [blacklists may accidentally treat bad input as safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_input_and_output_handling#Whitelist_or_Blacklist.3F).